# Python-Kafka : Program running in interactive mode and not in script mode

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to send some messages to a Kafka topic in `Machine_2` through a python script in `Machine_1`. Both `Machine_2` and `Machine_1` are in the same network and both are VM's in Azure.

**Code: sampl.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
Producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['Machine_2:9092'])
Producer.send('test', 'hello')
```

If I run the above code as

> python sampl.py

There is no messages reaching to the `Machine_2`. However, If I do:

> python -i sampl.py

Then the messages reach to the `Machine_2`. I checked the same using `kafka-console-consumer.sh`. I did `yum update` in `Machine_1` thinking there might be some libraries missing here. But no luck yet.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of kafka-python and kafka brokers are you using?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Kafka version - -0.10.2.0, pytho kafka module - kafka_python-1.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

kafka-python maintainer here. `Producer.send('test', b'hello')` is asynchronous and does not provide immediate delivery. What you are likely seeing is that the python interpreter is shutting down before the producer has a chance to complete the network send.

If you want to wait until the message is sent before finishing the script, you should use .get(timeout=...). So try:

`Producer.send('test', b'hello').get(timeout=1000)`

Or alternately, you can call flush() to do the same for all unsent messages:

`Producer.flush(timeout=1000)`

Comment: What is the default periodic intervals in which the producer sends the messges? What if it doesn't send within the timeout period?

Comment: kafka-python does not use a periodic interval for sending. Data can be buffered internally to create larger batches for higher throughput, but this is disabled by default. See the docs for more details: http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html